# Join multiple rows into one column using a function in Oracle with 3 related tables

Tags: sql, oracle, function, string, plsql

I know there are multiple questions about this same question but I couldn't find one that would fix my problem. I also know about this [article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) and that's exactly what I used for the code below. I'm just having a little problem...

**table_a:**

```
a_id    a_name
1       aaa
2       bbb
3       ccc
```

**table_b:**

```
b_id    b_name
1       ddd
2       eee
3       fff
```

**table_c**

```
a_id    b_id
1       2
1       3
2       1
3       1
3       2
3       3
```

I have the tables above and I need a SELECT statement that accomplishes this:

```
a_name  list_of_b_name
aaa     eee,fff
bbb     ddd
ccc     ddd,eee,fff
```

Maybe there are some Oracle functions I can use to simplify the process, like WM_CONCAT (haven't tried), but I need to use a FUNCTION and this is my attempt after looking at the article linked above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION f_test(id IN table_c.a_id % TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_text  VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT b_id FROM table_c WHERE a_id = id) LOOP
    l_text := l_text || ',' || cur_rec.b_id;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(l_text, ',');
END;
```

And then the SELECT goes like this:

```
SELECT a_id, f_test(a_id)
FROM table_c
GROUP BY a_id;
```

As expected by the code above (not not what I want, this is what I get):

```
a_id    list_of_b_id
1       2,3
2       1
3       1,2,3
```

I've tried many things with both the SELECT and FUNCTION code but I can't seem to do what I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your function to resemble:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(IN_ID IN TABLE_C.a_id%TYPE) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS

  l_text  VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;

BEGIN

  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT b.b_name 
                    FROM TABLE_B b
                    JOIN TABLE_C c ON c.b_id = b.b_id
                   WHERE c.a_id = IN_ID) LOOP
    l_text := l_text || ',' || cur_rec.b_id;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN LTRIM(l_text, ',');

END;
```

Then, you can use:

```
SELECT a.a_name, 
       f_test(a.a_id)
  FROM TABLE_A a
```

Answer (score 1):

change the SQL Query to get the list of bnames instead of b_ids

from

```
SELECT b_id FROM table_c WHERE a_id = id
```

to

```
SELECT b_name 
  FROM table_b b, table_c c 
   WHERE b.b_id = c.c_id
     and b.a_id = id
```

Instead of getting the IDs from table b, you should instead be getting the names.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @OMGPonies points out, you need to rewrite the function so it retrieves the required data from TABLE_B.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2      (p_id in table_c.a_id%type)
  3      return varchar2
  4  is
  5      l_text  varchar2(32767) := null;
  6  begin
  7      for cur_rec in (select b_name
  8                      from table_c c
  9                              join table_b b
 10                                  on (b.b_id = c.b_id)
 11                      where c.a_id = p_id)
 12      loop
 13          l_text := l_text || ',' || cur_rec.b_name;
 14      end loop;
 15      return ltrim(l_text, ',');
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Likewise you need to join to TABLE_A in the query:

```
SQL> select a.a_name
  2          , f_test(c.a_id)
  3  from table_c c
  4          join table_a a
  5              on (a.a_id = c.a_id)
  6  group by a.a_name
  7  /
        , f_test(c.a_id)
                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL>
```

Oh, that was a surprise.  The point is, F_TEST is not a aggregating function, so GROUP BY doesn't work here unless we include the function as well:

```
SQL> select a.a_name
  2          , f_test(c.a_id) 
  3  from table_c c
  4          join table_a a
  5              on (a.a_id = c.a_id)
  6  group by a.a_name, f_test(c.a_id)
  7  /

A_N F_TEST(C.A_ID)
--- ---------------------------------------------
bbb ddd
ccc ddd,eee,fff
aaa eee,fff

SQL>
```

Incidentally, without the GROUP BY clause we would get six rows (one for each row in TABLE_C).  Which we don't want.

The problem with the solution is one of performance: the function is executed once for each row in TABLE_C.  That loop on TABLE_B would get a bit expensive if either table were large.  The aggregating solution is more efficient:

```
SQL> select a.a_name
  2          , wm_concat(b.b_name) 
  3  from table_c c
  4          join table_b b
  5              on (b.b_id = c.b_id)
  6          join table_a a
  7              on (a.a_id = c.a_id)
  8  group by a.a_name
  9  /

A_N WM_CONCAT(B.B_NAME)
--- ---------------------------------------------
aaa fff,eee
bbb ddd
ccc fff,eee,ddd

SQL>
```

Comment: You don't need the GROUP BY to use the function, nor do you need the JOIN outside of the function.

Comment: @OMGPonies -That is true for your solution, because you have  implemented the function and the query to drive off TABLE_A.  The OP posted something different, and I implemented that.  if there are records in TABLE_A which are not in TABLE_C your solution will return a different result set from mine (unless you amended the query to join to TABLE_C, which I think would be inelegant - two selects on the same table).  Now maybe there will always be rows in TABLE_C for every row in TABLE_A, but the OP has not vouchsafed that business rule to us.

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to remember every little detail... And yes, there will always be entries from TABLE_A in TABLE_C. Sorry.