# Should I handle this HTML string construction with a custom Oracle function or PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, function, string, plsql

While implementing the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372701/join-multiple-rows-into-one-column-using-a-function-in-oracle-with-3-related-tabl) on my project I realized there's 3 way I can accomplish something but I have no idea which one is better. Is there a performance again using one over the other? Is that performance worth the more complicated implementation? That's the kind of stuff I want to know.

Although I did not specify, that question was about selecting a movie info from a table and join every genre in a single column separated by commas. Now, I need those genres to be clickable in my code so I can filter by the clicked genre.

I thought of 3 ways to do this:

**Solution 1)**

Use 1 SELECT query and the function on that other question than use PHP to build the HTML string. Something like this:

```
$genres = explode(',', $info['GENRES']);
$count = count($genres);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $genres[$i] = '<a href="#">'.$genres[$i].'</a>';
}

$info['GENRES'] = implode(' | ', $genres);
```

Then I realized I'm missing the genre ID so I can easily create a link to filter by that genre and I thought of changing the Oracle function to include it. How? By creating a JSON string (ie: `{"1":"Action","2":"Crime","5":"Thriller"}`, the function can easily be modified for this) and it's a simple matter of adapting the code above accordingly.

**Solution 2)**

Use 2 SELECT statements and completely ignore the function on that other question. One query to select the movie info, the other to select all genres (id and name) associated to that movie. Then PHP would do the rest to build the HTML code string.

**Solution 3)**

Simply use 1 SELECT query and the Oracle function adapted to construct the whole string by itself. Meaning, the PHP code would be as simple as executing the SQL statement. The Oracle function would prepare the whole HTML string.

Now, this solution may not work as I really need it, rendering it irrelevant. But I don't know that cause I'm not sure how exactly I'm going to build those HTML links to filter by genre, haven't really thought about it yet. Well, in PHP I can always do it, one way or another, not sure I can do the same in an Oracle function.

Still, let's assume it's possible, I believe it is.

**Which solution should I go for?**

Is there any reason, in this situation, for the Oracle function to do all the work (or vice-versa)? Given this, should I go with solution 3 or solution 1/2?

If solution 1/2 is the better way, which one should I go for? Solution 1 has 1 SELECT in the PHP code but another in the Oracle function. Solution 2 has 2 SELECTs in the PHP code. Is there a performance gain on one over the other or they are basically the same? If so, which one is better?

Solution 1 has a simpler PHP code but introduces a slightly more complicated code for the Oracle function. In the other hand, solution 2 has no Oracle function code at all and the PHP code will increase in size/complexity, not by much though.

I'm inclined towards solution 1, but would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote is for solution #2. Yes, you will have more actual data retrievals, but your data is being used in a much more normalized manner. There's nothing stopping you from creating an array from the second retrieval and creating a Comma-Sep list with `explode()`.

Comment: No need to create an array from the second retrieval if I go with solution 2, I would simply loop over all the genres and build the whole string. The `explode()/implode()` is needed because I have a string separated by commas in solution 1, but I don't have that in solution 2. What I don't like in solution 2 is that with PHP/Oracle I need to call `oci_parse()` followed by `oci_execute()` and then `oci_fetch_*()` 2 times, one for the movie info and another for the genres, it's lots of code, solution 1 is simpler.

Comment: Correct, there is no need to create an array, but perhaps it would be easier for interfacing to your existing code (which seems to use arrays already). Solution #1 is perfectly fine, too - I can hear my DB Normalization professor screaming about it though. As in most cases, any of the three solutions will yield the same end result. It's a matter of your own preference.

Comment: Yes, but my intention with this question is more about performance and what's "better". I'm just starting working with Oracle and I'm basically trying to understand if there's any benefit in using a function implemented in Oracle versus doing all the work in PHP. What would by your professor's problem with that implementation? The JSON thing? I also though of creating separate functions, one with a list of names and the other with a list of ids, I would simply have to match them in PHP. But I thought the JSON method would work and look better.

Comment: What you're doing wouldn't totally kill my prof. You are *storing* the data in a normalized fashion, after all. If the genres were stored with commas, that would be the worst :)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different option entirely?

It looks like you're querying data in a one-to-many situation. That is, a movie record has some number of genre records associated with it. I'm not sure if PHP (or the drivers) supports this, but your result set may itself contain a cursor to another result set. Imagine a query like below. Note that I have no idea what your table names are - I'm making stuff up based off your other question.

```
SELECT MOVIE_ID, CURSOR( 
    SELECT  MOVIE_TO_GENRE_TABLE.GENRE_ID 
    FROM    MOVIE_TO_GENRE_TABLE 
    WHERE   MOVIE_TO_GENRE_TABLE.MOVIE_ID = MOVIE_TABLE.MOVIE_ID
  ) as genre_cursor
FROM MOVIE_TABLE
WHERE ....
```

By doing this you get to have a single query (one hit to the database) which returns all the data you need. Then you can have PHP do the HTML generation, what it's really meant to do. No PL/SQL functions (which may severly impact performance) nor are you de-normalizing and re-normalizing data.

Comment: 1) So, even if I have a SELECT inside another SELECT (like that), it's still a single query? Just curious, in my code there's 1 SELECT and another inside the function, does that count as 1 too or not? 2) The "problem" with that situation is that every time I have a more complex problem where I think I could solve it with functions (which I'm forced to use on this project), there's always a more complex SELECT statement to solve it lolol (haven't tested it yet though).

Comment: Just tried it, looks a nice solution and the SELECT makes sense. But for my real problem I would need 3 cursors and that would make the PHP code very complex. It's simpler with the JSON method...

Comment: The issue with using the function to give the comma-separated-values column is that you may have a performance implication. Each row in the result set now invokes the function, which then performs a single query. With a large result set that's many small queries. Also, you pay a "context switch" penalty going from SQL to PL/SQL.